# Why the node.js script is call twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in Node.js
I write the first script in Node.js like the below:

```
var count = 0;
var http = require('http');
var serv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    count++;
    console.log("why two?:" + count);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    require('colors');
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        console.log('count:' + count);
        console.log('smashing node'.rainbow);
        res.end('<marquee>Smashing Node</marquee>');
    } else {
        console.log('count:' + count);
        console.log('WTF'.rainbow);
        res.end('<h4>Smashing Node</h4>');
    }
});
serv.listen(3000);
```

Then I run this script

## node first.js

In browser, access http://localhost:3000
And the result in console is:

```
why two?:1
count:1
WTF
why two?:2
count:2
smashing node
```

Why the code is called twice?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are not sending two requests? Check your devtools console

Comment: When I use Safari to access the url, the code is just called once. But in the Chrome, it is called twice. And I check the Network in devtools, the url is sent once

Answer (score 6):

Because two requests are being made.

Probably one is for `/` and the other is for `/favicon.ico`.

Your code doesn't care what the path is when it handles a request.

You can test that by looking in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools or examining the contents of the `req` object.

Comment: I just tested the code and i confirm, the second request is for `/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
var http = require('http');
var serv = http.createServer(); 
serv.on('request',function(req,res){
    count++;
    console.log("why two?:" + count);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    if (req.url=='/') {
        console.log(req.method);
        console.log(req.headers);
        console.log(req.url);
        res.end('<marquee>Smashing Node</marquee>');
    } 
});
serv.listen(3000);
```

in this it checks only for the `'/'` url and then responds....so the marquee is returned

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

That anonymous function is called whenever you request on http://localhost:3000

So maybe somehow you're requesting twice (e.g. for / and /favicon.ico)
Try opening chrome dev tools, and in console tab you'll maybe see an error, that favicon.ico wasn't found.

or you can use [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) to keep track of requests:

```
var app = require('express')();
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

It will log every request, with codes and URL-s. It needs express though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is helpful for the future debuging